# Where in functions.php to add this code so thumbnail images display?

Tags: post-thumbnails

Thumbnail images are not displaying by blog excerpts on my blog at http://richardclunan.com/blog/ -- I found some code that I think I might need to add to functions.php to make this happen, and if I do need to do this, I'd like to know where in functions.php I should add the code...

In my twentyeleven files, in functions.php, it says:

// This theme uses Featured Images (also known as post thumbnails) for per-post/per-page Custom Header images
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

But the following code isn't in functions.php:

if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}

If my understanding of this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails is correct, then maybe I have to add that code into functions.php to make thumbnails appear on my blog ...?

Where in the file functions.php would I add the code?

And I presume curly brackets } signify the end of lines of code -- so I guess I'd paste the code after a curly bracket somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post thumbnails are enabled in the twenty-eleven theme by default. If it's not working either you have a plugin conflict, or someone has edited the functions.php file. Here is the section of the twenty-eleven functions.php file that should enable the post thumbnails:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

The code needs to be inside the `function twentyeleven_setup()` function to work.

Comment: I think it's safe to say you don't have to use if ( function_exists( anymore. This was used for backwards compatibility, but shouldn't be an issue in current WordPress versions.